# Allow Synaptics Touchpad Windows-Key Window Snapping

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, autohotkey, touchpad

I was dying to find an easy way to do the Windows-Key + Arrow window snapping functions using the Synaptics touchpad on my Lenovo Yoga 11s.

This would be perfect for 3/4 finger swipes left and right but I could not find any way to customize the actions performed for those Touchpad gestures.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to use the Tap Zones feature of the touch-pad software and assign a macro to edge taps.

Synaptic WILL let you modify the settings for Tapping, Enable Tap zones and then assign the action of 'Record and play a sequence of keystrokes' to a tap in any one of the corner zones. Sounds great, right? Unfortunately you CANNOT assign any kind of windows-key action through the macro sequence recorder.

The solution for me was to use AutoHotKey and bind Synaptic to something like `Ctrl+Alt+[` then modify the AutoHotKey script to Send #{Left}.

My AutoHotKey script looks like this:

```
^![::
send #{Left} ; winkey left is bound to synaptics Bottom-Left action
Exit

^!]::
send #{Up} ; winkey up gets bound to synaptics Upper-left action
Exit
```

Now just make sure you temporarily 'Suspend Hotkeys' in AutoHotKey while you are recording your `Ctrl+Alt+[` macro or it won't be able properly record the keypresses.